# Remove left and right indentation of abstract

Tags: indentation, abstract

Trying to remove the indentation which is appearing around my abstract for some unknown reason. A MWE is below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % formatting rules for the English language
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % proper formatting for accented characters and non-standard characters such as pipelines
\usepackage{mathptmx}% fot a font which looks like Times New Roman (serif/roman)
%\usepackage{tgtermes}% an altternative
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}% for a font which looks like Helvetica, scaled to match TNR (sans)
%\usepackage{tgheros}% an altternative
\usepackage{courier}% for a font which looks like Courier (typewriter/monospaced)
%\usepackage{tgcursor}% an altternative
\usepackage[top=15mm, bottom=15mm, left=30mm, right=30mm]{geometry} % page layout
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm} % Do not indent the 1st line of a paragraph.
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}   % Add space between paragraphs.


%% redefine \footnoterule for using the whole text width
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern-3\p@\hrule\@width\columnwidth\kern 2.6\p@
}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*\abstractname{\flushleft\textbf{ABSTRACT}\hfill}
\begin{abstract}
\noindent This is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstract
\end{abstract}

Some other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuff
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `abstract` package which allows for indent/margin settings via `\setlength` definitions. See http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/abstract/abstract.pdf for the documentation.

In this case, I have set `\absleftindent` and `\absrightindent` both to **0mm**. Change at will.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % formatting rules for the English language
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % proper formatting for accented characters and non-standard characters such as pipelines
\usepackage{mathptmx}% fot a font which looks like Times New Roman (serif/roman)
%\usepackage{tgtermes}% an altternative
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}% for a font which looks like Helvetica, scaled to match TNR (sans)
%\usepackage{tgheros}% an altternative
\usepackage{courier}% for a font which looks like Courier (typewriter/monospaced)
%\usepackage{tgcursor}% an altternative
\usepackage[top=15mm, bottom=15mm, left=30mm, right=30mm]{geometry} % page layout

%%%% Additions for TeX.StackExchange
\usepackage{abstract}
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0mm}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0mm}


\setlength{\parindent}{0mm} % Do not indent the 1st line of a paragraph.
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}   % Add space between paragraphs.


%% redefine \footnoterule for using the whole text width
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern-3\p@\hrule\@width\columnwidth\kern 2.6\p@
}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*\abstractname{\flushleft\textbf{ABSTRACT}\hfill}
\begin{abstract}
\noindent This is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstractThis is my abstract
\end{abstract}

Some other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other stuffSome other

 stuff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The package also provides a ``absparindent`` macro to adjust the paragraph indentation in the abstract, but setting ``\setlength{\absparindent}{0em}`` has no effect here.

Comment: Re my previous comment, it's because the ``abstract`` package contains a line that sets the length of ``\absparindent`` to the length of ``\parindent``. I find this very odd, since that cancels the effect of changing ``\absparindent``.