# Remove indentation from abstract environment with etoolbox

Tags: indentation, etoolbox, abstract

I have the abstract for my paper on a separate page, hence there is no need to have the extra indentation on either side of the `abstract` environment to indicate that it is an abstract.

There is an answer to how to do that in [How to adjust the width of abstract?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151583/how-to-adjust-the-width-of-abstract), in which it seems to me that the entire definition of the `abstract` environment is repeated with an adjustment of the `setlength` macro within that definition.

I am, however, already using `etoolbox` to remove indentation in the `abstract` environment (following [lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep)'s suggestion to [Remove paragraph indent from abstract in article class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1597/remove-paragraph-indent-from-abstract-in-article-class)), and in that case, the entire definition of the `abstract` is not repeated - it simply adds something extra to the existing definition.

I am, therefore, wondering if I could do the same to remove the indentation. Can I use `etoolbox` to remove the indentation in a similar way as is done below to remove the indentation?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,etoolbox}
\ifundef{\abstract}{}{\patchcmd{\abstract}%
    {\quotation}{\quotation\noindent\ignorespaces}{}{}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{abstract}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{abstract}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173028/remove-left-and-right-indentation-of-abstract/173036#173036 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on Christian's comment, it's probably easiest to do this with the [`abstract`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/abstract) package and the `\absleftindent`/`\absrightindent` macros. Note, however, that this package contains the following line:

```
AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\absparindent}{\parindent}}
```

The effect of that line means that changing the paragraph indent of the `abstract` environment with `\absparindent` has no effect, since it's automatically reverted to the global setting of `\parindent` anyway. The only way I've found to avoid this is to first set `\parindent` to whatever you want `\absparindent` to be, and then change `\parindent` to what you actually want `\parindent` to be. Maybe there's a better way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,abstract}
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0em}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0em}
\parindent = 0em % use this instead of \absparindent
\AtBeginDocument{\parindent = 1.5em} % then set \parindent
\begin{document}
    \begin{abstract}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{abstract}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you not set the `\absparindent` right after `\begin{document}`? See my 'other' answer below

Comment: @ChristianHupfer See my comment to your answer ``:)``

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{abstract}

%\setlength{\absparindent}{0em}%
%\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\absparindent}{0em}}
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0em}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0em}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\absparindent}{0em}
    \begin{abstract}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{abstract}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but I prefer to avoid putting global non-document specific settings inside the actual document (they go in a custom ``.sty`` file I make instead). That way I don't have to remember to repeat it every time I write a document in that style.

Comment: @Ok, that is true -- using `\AtBeginDocument` is the correct way.